# Authenticate in Identity with an external login page

Tags: identityserver4

So, we are developing a public rest api that is protected by our own Identity server through an authorization code flow. Somewhere in the middle of the flow, we also implemented a consent step (with a different web app) to grant the Api access to some data that belongs to a user's account of another web app of our own. Currently, the consent page is protected by OpenIdConnect, which login page is implemented in the Identity server itself. However, we want expose as little as possible of the Identity server to the public.

With that in mind, is it possible to implement a login page outside of the Identity server that can still authenticate the user in identity and grant the consent? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I will start with just explaining the flow.

1. When an app redirects a user to Identityserver, they come to *authorize endpoint* to validate the request.
2. When request is not valid, that triggers an error.
3. When request is valid and **user is authenticated** (has auth cookie) they just go back to the client app with the code.
4. When request is valid and the user is **not authenticated**, the next redirect would be to *login page*. It is the place to check the credentials, **set the cookie** (for the Identityserver app) and redirect back to the *authorize endpoint* to go further with *consent* or final redirect to the client app.

Is the answer crystal clear already? Login page is almost the only vitally needed for Identityserver to make possible setting the auth cookie for any further SSO.

Nevertheless you can delegate the login handling to an external app (one more Identityserver instance?). In that case your front login app will perform the steps (1-2-3-4), set the first level cookie, redirect back to the client Identityserver app, which will set the second level cookie on *external auth callback* action and finally redirect to the original caller. Is this the scenario for you? Possibly so. The original explanation is a bit uncertain.

Comment: The issue wasn't really about the flow, it was about whether or not it was possible to delegate the login. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I believe understanding the flow helps to see the answer yourself. If it doesn't, I answered explicitly: **you have to set the cookie**, internal login page is the most straightforward place to do that, but you can easily fallback to an external idp. That's the explicit answer to your question. Personally I successfully and for several years maintain an instance of IdSrv without any login page. It redirects to an Open LDAP-based 3rd-party system for user authentication.